# How can I make ViewContext available in my viewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

In my controller I have the following code:

```
var viewModel = new ListCityViewModel {
                City = rowData,
                Meta =
                {
                    DataSourceID = dataSourceID,
                    Em0 = em0
                }
            };
```

In my viewModel I have the following:

```
public class ListCityViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ListCitiesViewModel()
    {
        Meta = new Meta
        {
            Title = ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue +
                    ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue,
            Desc = ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue +
                    ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue
        };
    }
    public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; } 
}
```

and:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public BaseViewModel()
    {
    }
    public Meta Meta { get; set; }
}
```

However it's not working as I get a message:

```
Error   6   An object reference is required for the non-static field, 
method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext.Controller.get'
```

Can anyone help me with this one. Do I need to pass something to the viewModel from the controller and how can I pass it. I have this viewModel common to many actions so I would like this to be automatic rather than me having to specify in the controller the controller name and action name.

Comment: How does ViewContext get into the viewmodel?  Also, I'm pretty sure the syntax ValueProvider["controller"].RawValue is invalid in ASP.NET MVC3.  It should be ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue.

Comment: Why are you looking to have this in a viewmodel? Is it specific to what you want to show or is this for logging purposes?

Comment: I have a common view model for a number of different actions. These are my admin screens. With these properties set then I'll use the values to show the page title etc.

Comment: The problem is my ViewContext doesn't get to the viewmodel. I'm not sure how to pass it there.

Comment: Why don't you have a method in a Controller Base Class that sets those properties, then in your action when you want a view model you can pass it to that method.

Comment: Greg - I guess this would be possible but I would still really like to have more information available in my viewModel. Maybe there is also some other information in the viewContext that I might like to use later.

Comment: Greg - What I am considering now is to use the OnActionExecuting method or the OnActionExecuted method to set the values. Not sure how to do this right now. Do you think this would be a good idea?

Comment: I would consider to change the design... From my part of view the view context should not be necessary in the view model...

Answer (score 0):

In short : do not do that. It is not the right thing to do in MVC pattern. Your viewmodels should be as dumb as possible, and without any "contexts". If you need some "meta" data in your view models, depending for example on route data (action, controller), write a custom filter, which will put it there in OnActionExecuted - for example look by reflection if the current viewmodel has your "meta" properties (by this you make your own convention) and fill them from route data.